# Displaying Explode data using loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, explode

I am new in PHP. I have a code in which i use foreach loop to display data in table of explode function.

Here i have a question

The data in my db is

[image]

Here you see After `Aatir` there is a blank space. When i use loop to print data

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "pacra1";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `pacra_clients` WHERE `id` = 50";

$conn->multi_query($sql);
$result = $conn->use_result();

echo $conn->error; 
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$liaison_one = $row['liaison_one'];

$liaison_one_chunks = explode(",", $liaison_one);

    echo '<table border="01">';
    foreach($liaison_one_chunks as $row){
        echo '<tr>';
        $row = explode(',',$row);
    foreach($row as $cell){
            echo '<td>';
            echo $cell;
            echo '</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

The result of my code is

[image]

In result you can see that there is a blank cell due to blank space in data.

**Is it possible that i can skip blank space which is in my data???**

Comment: `$row = $result->fetch_assoc($sql);`

Comment: Add an `if()` condition that when the string is `empty()`, don't create a row

Comment: ^ or `foreach($row as $cell) { if(!empty($cell)) { echo "<td>{$cell}</td>"; }}`

Comment: Why don't you put al these values in different fields in your MySQL table?

Comment: @Fin lets suppose in future i want to some more data like address of that person. For that i create new column every time when i update data. and its difficult to handle. That why i use `Implode` and `Explode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Use [continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php).

```
 foreach($row as $cell){
            if ($cell == "")
                   continue;
            echo '<td>';
            echo $cell;
            echo '</td>';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 foreach($row as $cell){
        if ($cell != "" && $cell != null)
        {
        echo '<td>';
        echo $cell;
        echo '</td>';
        }
    }
```